# Perl WWW::Mechanize Slow down requests to avoid HTTP Code 429

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I've written a Perl script that will fetch and parse a webpage, fill some forms and collect some information, but after a while I was denied by the server with HTTP error `429 Too Many Requests`. I sent too many requests in a short amount of time to the server so my IP has been blacklisted.

How could I "slow down" my requests/script to avoid this again and not hurt anyone? Is there any way to do this with Perl module [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize)?

```
sub getlinksofall {

    for my $i ( 1 .. $maxpages ) {

        $mech->follow_link( url_regex => qr/page$i/i );
        push @LINKS, $mech->find_all_links(
            url_regex => qr/http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/somestuffs\//i
        );
    }

    foreach my $links (@LINKS) {
        push @LINKS2, $links->url();
    }

    @new_stuffs = uniq @LINKS2;
}

sub getnumberofpages {
    push @numberofpages, $mech->content =~ m/\/page(\d+)"/gi;
    $maxpages = ( sort { $b <=> $a } @numberofpages )[0];
}

sub getdataabout {

    foreach my $stuff ( @new_stuffs ) {

        $mech->get($stuff);

        $g = $mech->content;
        $t = $mech->content;
        $s = $mech->content;

        # ... and than some regex match with some DBI stuff...
    }
}
```

By these loops there could be thousands of links and I just want to slow it down. Is some "sleep" command in these loops enough for this?

Comment: It depends on the server how many requests it allows. Sleeping for a second between each request would most likely work. You would have to put it at the end of your `foreach` loop where you iterate `@new_stuff`. https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::HiRes allows you to `sleep` for less than a second. Keep in mind that you might be violating the terms of services of the website you are trying to parse, and that the rate limit might be there for a reason. Best ask them if you are allowed to do what you are doing.

Comment: thanks for your comment!

Comment: @simbabque: *"the rate limit might be there for a reason"* I assume that's sarcastic?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check whether the site you are scraping has a *service agreement* that allows you to use it in this way. Because bandwidth costs money, most sites prefer to restrict access to real human operators or legitimate index engines like Google

You should also take a look at the `robots.txt` file for the site you're leeching which will have details on exactly what automated access is permitted. Take a look at [www.robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/) for more information

A simple `sleep 30` between requests will probably be okay to get you past most rules, but *don't* reduce the period below 30

There is also a subclass of `LWP::UserAgent` called [`LWP::RobotUA`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::RobotUA) that is intended for situations like this. It may well be straightforward to get `WWW::Mechanize` to use this instead of the base class

Comment: Sleep 30 would be too much in this case. I will contact the admins of this webiste if I can use such things on their site.

Btw. the idea of LWP::RobotUA is awesome. Thank you!

Comment: @guyfromnowhere: 30 seconds between requests is pretty standard. You couldn't submit requests manually and write down the results much faster than that. If you want the site's data then ask for it -- it would be much cheaper for them to give you a copy of the database if they're willing for you to have it, and if they don't want you to have it then you shouldn't be breaking the law to get it

Comment: Yes, exactly. I will contact them.